# 7D simple Lie algebras over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, finite-fields, computer-algebra, modular-lie-algebras

Up to isomorphism, what are all the seven-dimensional simple Lie algebras over the field with three elements?

Comment: Do you have a sense of the order of magnitude of the number of such algebras?  (I don't.)

Comment: I’m pretty sure there are at least three.

Comment: The question is too narrow for my taste. I would be more interested in some general classification statement about simple Lie algebras over $\mathbb F_3$ (possibly of small dimension, but not just dimension $7$).

Comment: Could you provide a bit of background or motivation?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny it’s the simplest case that cannot be answered by using https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/liealgdb/doc/chap0.html

Comment: @DanielSebald it would be helpful to give more context (e.g., giving the number of simple Lie algebras in dimension up to 6)